# Организация "платформонезависимого" создания файлов в JAVA

Tags: java, linux, windows, файлы

Есть пример кода:

```
private void analyzeCurve() throws IOException {
    if (listX.isEmpty() || listY.isEmpty()) {
        WorkspaceWindow.showWarningMessage(EMPTY_DRAWING_LIST);
    } else {
        ArrayList<Integer> lx;
        ArrayList<Integer> ly;
        File xmlFile = new File(File.separator + "tmp" + File.separator + "xmlFile.xml"); //создание файла
        FileWriter fr = new FileWriter(xmlFile);
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fr);
        //действия с файлом...
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

При запуске под системами Linux файл успешно создается и в него идет запись. Но во время запуска кода в Windows файл не создается.
Получаем исключение:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \tmp\xmlFile (Системе не удается найти указанный путь)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:90)
    at client.logic.Analyzer.analyzeCurve(Analyzer.java:69)
    at client.logic.Analyzer.run(Analyzer.java:43)
```

Связано это, как я понимаю, с отсутствием директории \tmp\ в Windows, но тогда возникает вопрос:
 1. Как создавать файлы в Windows и Linux в папке tmp, то есть в папке для временных файлов?
 2. Можно ли каким то образом понять, в какой системе мы находимся и зависимо от этого задавать путь создания файлов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Есть готовый статический метод, решающий вашу задачу [Files.createTempFile()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#Files.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...))
2. Если вам для какой-то другой задачи потребуется узнать текущую ОС, воспользуйтесь этим фрагментом:

   ```
   String os = System.getProperty("os.name")
   ```

Comment: Спасибо, но предполагается, что файл, который я создаю является промежуточным, который далее должен быть сохранен под новым именем в новом месте на диске. Смогу ли я так сделать с временным файлом?

Comment: @VVRud, конечно сможете. С точки зрения ОС нет такого понятия как "сохранить файл под новым именем". Вы либо перемещаете куда-то существующий файл (`Files.copy()`) либо сохраняете данные, которые висят у вас в памяти в какой-то другой произвольный файл.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте воспользоваться классом `java.nio.file.Path`:

```
Path path = Paths.get("tmp", "file.txt");
Path file = Files.createFile(path);
```